# JavaScript-библиотеки SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics)

Tags: svg, вектор, pdf, javascript

Есть два вопроса об SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics):

1. Какую JavaScript библиотеку лучше использовать для создания векторной SVG графики?
2. Можно ли потом полученную векторную SVG графику, из браузера, экпортировать в PDF файл? Если да, то как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**jQuery SVG**
[jQuery SVG](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html)
Хорошо написанна и документирована. Много примеров и демонстраций. Поддерживает большинство SVG элементы, позволяет легкий доступ к элементам.

**Raphaël—JavaScript Library**
[Raphaeljs/](http://raphaeljs.com/)
хорошая библиоиека для начинающих, можно легко и быстро сделать много вещей с SVG. 
Хорошо написанна и документирована. Много примеров и демонстрационных материалов. Расширяемая архитектура. Богата анимационными эффектами.

Для конвертирования в PDF:
[Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) (Java, open source)
[Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) (native binary, open source)
Batik даст вам больше контроля. С Inkscape, вы можете использовать параметры командной строки (- экспорт в PDF IIRC)